# Issue with sharing on facebook using sharekit

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ios4, sharekit

I am using sharekit for facebook and twitter integration.My problem is when i log in using facebook credentials i am not able to post any text,image or url.I have configured the **SHKFacebookKey** & **SHKFacebookSecret** in the configuration file.

I get a facebook login page and after successful login the page dissapears and nothing happens.

**Note:** I had to make changes in **SHKTwitter** file to get twitter working.

Thanks,

Aditya

Comment: I found using ShareKit pretty hard if the only task you want to achieve is posting to Facebook, Twitter and Email. I wrote my own simple lib [BMSocialShare](http://github.com/blockhaus/BMSocialShare). ShareKit is better in case you need to post to many different social services.

Answer (score 0):

Have you put you facebook app key in info.plist? please try to put your facebook app key with prefix fbxxxxxxxxxx. 
Once login done from facebook app, your app will get a call with facebook login response.

Please take a look [Installing sharekit](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit)

Hope this will work.